# Sql to Linq lambda expressions

Tags: linq

I have an SQL Query and I want to convert it to Linq.
This is my SQL Query.

```
SELECT e.Name,e.EntityId,p.QId,p.Points
FROM Entity e
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT * FROM EntityPoints WHERE EntityPoints.QId = 2) p
ON e.EntityId = p.EntityId
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my model

```css
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<c_Entity> Entity = new List<c_Entity>();
        List<c_EntityPoints> EntityPoints = new List<c_EntityPoints>();

        var results = from e in Entity
                      join p in EntityPoints
                      on e.EntityId equals p.EntityId
                      select new
                      {
                          Name = e.Name,
                          EntityId = e.EntityId,
                          QID = p.QID,
                          Points = p.Points
                      };
    }
}
public class c_Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string EntityId { get; set; }
    public string QID { get; set; }
    public string Points { get; set; }
}
public class c_EntityPoints
{
    public string EntityId { get; set; }
    public string QID { get; set; }
    public string Points { get; set; }

}
```